# Subdomain does not work for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, installation, subdomain

I've a `Subdomain` under a `maindomain`. I want to install `CodeIgniter` under `subdomain`. But `subdomain` does not work for `CodeIgniter` default `route`.

Like my `subdomain` is `demo.example.com` not working. Normally `core php` is working for this `subdomain` but `CodeIgniter` not.

But when I call `demo.example.com/welcome` then working. Here `welcome` is a `Controller` name.

Can anyone help me what is my wrong ?

My Base URL is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://demo.example.com';
```

My .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

My default controller(`welcome.php`) is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
echo 'Welcome Subdomain';
}
}
```

Comment: instead of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: Thank's for your ans. But it's still same problem. Can you give a better solution for this problem ?

Comment: replace all code with this code : `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`

Comment: you missed `RewriteBase /` in your `.htacess`

Comment: Nope, it's not working.

Comment: can you try `RewriteBase /demo/`? if folder name is `demo`

Comment: Still same, not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127861/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-al-amin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller name is `Welcome.php` as a `public_html/demo/application/controllers/Welcome.php`.

Please change instead `Welcome.php` to `welcome.php`

Set instead `$route['default_controller'] = "Welcome"` to `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome"` in `routes.php`

Comment: On Ci3 versions you need first letter upper case as specified here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

If you have CodeIgniter install in your main domain add RewriteBase / in your .htaccess

Comment: I've CodeIgniter project in my main domain. But `RewriteBase /` not working.